# Error when using operators with a generic type

Tags: rust

I'm learning rust and I can't understand why the following code gives an error.

```
use std::ops::Mul;
use std::ops::Add;

struct Vec2<T>
{
    x: T,
    y: T,
}

impl<T: Mul + Add> Vec2<T> {
    fn magnitude_squared(&self) -> T {
        self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y // error here
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Vec2 { x: 1f32, y: 1f32 };
    println!("{}", x.magnitude_squared());
}
```

Error message (doesn't make much sense to me unless multiplication of two floats produces some 'non-addable' type):

> src\main.rs(14,9): error E0369: binary operation `+` cannot be applied
>   to type `<T as std::ops::Mul>::Output`
>   help: run `rustc --explain E0369` to see a detailed explanation
>   note: an implementation of `std::ops::Add` might be missing for `<T as std::ops::Mul>::Output`

Rust compiler `rustc 1.11.0 (9b21dcd6a 2016-08-15)`
The code is similar to [this](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/traits.html#trait-bounds-on-generic-structs) example. What's the difference that makes my code wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message tells you what to do: you need to add an `Add` implementation for `<T as Mul>::Output`.

You can do so by adding a trait bound on your `impl` as such:

```
use std::ops::Mul;
use std::ops::Add;

struct Vec2<T: Copy>
{
    x: T,
    y: T,
}

impl<T> Vec2<T>
    where T: Copy + Mul,
          <T as Mul>::Output: Add<Output=T>
{
    fn magnitude_squared(&self) -> T {
        self.x * self.x + self.y * self.y
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = Vec2 { x: 1f32, y: 1f32 };
    println!("{}", x.magnitude_squared());
}
```

The `Copy` was added to simplify this answer.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that in your solution, `T*T` could be a completely different type `M`, as long as adding two `M` together gives a `T` again?

Comment: @ChrisEmerson: yes, you are right.

Comment: Is it correct to say that a rust compiler does type checking before substitution, so it is necessary to specify traits for trait types explicitly?(I hope my wording makes sense).

Comment: @DmitryKuznetsov Yes, unlike C++, Rust requires that we specify the traits over generic types to use the methods from these traits in a generic function.