# Is there a trait for scalar-castable types?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm stuck with this code for operator overloading.

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct Test<T: Add>{
    m:T
}

impl<T:Add> Add for Test<T>{
    type Output = Test<T>;
    fn add(self, rhs: Test<T>) -> Test<T> {
        Test { m: (self.m + rhs.m) as T }
    }
}
```

I cannot cast `(self.m + rhs.m)` to `T` because it is a `non-scalar cast`.

Is there a trait for types scalar-castable to `T`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't a trait covering this functionality. Only some casts are possible and their full list can be found in [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/casting-between-types.html).

As for your `Add` implementation, you should modify it in the following manner in order for it to work:

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct Test<T: Add>{
    m: T
}

impl<T> Add for Test<T> where T: Add<Output = T> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        Test { m: self.m + rhs.m }
    }
}
```

You can find a good explanation why the additional `T: Add<Output = T>` bound is necessary in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29184450/1870153). [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39170088/1870153) might be even closer to your exact case.