# Why does Rust not allow coercion to trait objects inside containers?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have a `Vec<Box<T>>` where `T` implements `Foo`. Why can I not coerce it to a `Vec<Box<Foo>>` even though I can coerce anything of type `Box<T>` into a `Box<Foo>`? Why does the below code not compile?

```
use std::vec;

trait Foo {}

struct Bar {}

impl Foo for Bar {}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![Box::new(Bar {})];
    let v_1 = v as Vec<Box<Foo>>;
}
```

Comment: Relevant to your interests: a [recent question on casts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41869048/is-there-a-trait-for-scalar-castable-types).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because `Box<Bar>` is a different size than `Box<Foo>`.  The coercion is allowed on a *single* value, but here you'd have to resize the whole vector.  The book goes into some detail on this in the section on [Representation of Trait Objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html#representation).  Short version: `Box<Bar>` is a pointer to a value.  `Box<Foo>` is a pointer to a value *and* a pointer to a vtable.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!